# NTP - Egypt DST time change 2023 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ntp

I have ntp server with OS Ubuntu 20.04

we will have new day light saving time change in Egypt on 27th of April 2023

I tried to check the dst status using "timedatectl" command but unfortunately it's not showing dst configuration status in the command output.

I have configured timezone to be "africa/cairo"
Moreover, in the ntp.conf file I configured the reference link to be "http://africa.pool.ntp.org/join.html"
server 0.africa.pool.ntp.org
server 1.africa.pool.ntp.org
server 2.africa.pool.ntp.org
server 3.africa.pool.ntp.org

I need support in the following:

- How to check DST status in ubuntu as it's not shown in "datetimectl" command output.
- Is it updated in ubuntu 20.04 to change time automatically for cairo timezone on 27th of April.
- Is NTP ubuntu server will change time automatically or I have to do a manual action.

Thank you

Comment: First of all NTP has nothing to do with time zones.  To check the DST dates throughout the years, I had written a Perl script https://kadifeli.com/fedon/hint.php?perl_dst You can test your time zone using that script.

Comment: From your question. Is it updated in ubuntu 20.04 to change time automatically for cairo timezone on 27th of April. That is a question for the developers none of which are volunteers here.

Comment: This reads like a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459637/mexico-ntp-no-more-time-changes-since-2023-and-my-ntp-server/1459642#1459642 - one's Mexico vs. Egypt but the point is still the same iwth regards to NTP.

Comment: @AhmedElshamy Please, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, NTP has nothing to do with time zones. All time calculation on NTP is done in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So, selecting a pool from Africa will not change anything, except the NTP servers that your system uses. All NTP servers return the "universal time" and not any kind of "local time."

**You should never update your system's clock manually, unless you have no other way to synchronize the clock automatically. Besides this, changing manually the clock because of DST or time zone changes, is absolutely WRONG!**

[Time zone databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) are regularly updated and Ubuntu will update itself, as long as you keep your system(s) in supported versions and updated through the `apt` command (or automatically).

By using the following commands on my fully updated (22.10) system:

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones | grep -i -e egypt -e cairo
Africa/Cairo
Egypt

$ zdump -v Egypt
Egypt  -9223372036854775808 = NULL
Egypt  -9223372036854689408 = NULL
Egypt  Sun Sep 30 21:54:50 1900 UT = Sun Sep 30 23:59:59 1900 LMT isdst=0 gmtoff=7509
[...]
Egypt  Thu Jul 31 21:59:59 2014 UT = Thu Jul 31 23:59:59 2014 EET isdst=0 gmtoff=7200
Egypt  Thu Jul 31 22:00:00 2014 UT = Fri Aug  1 01:00:00 2014 EEST isdst=1 gmtoff=10800
Egypt  Thu Sep 25 20:59:59 2014 UT = Thu Sep 25 23:59:59 2014 EEST isdst=1 gmtoff=10800
Egypt  Thu Sep 25 21:00:00 2014 UT = Thu Sep 25 23:00:00 2014 EET isdst=0 gmtoff=7200
Egypt  9223372036854689407 = NULL
Egypt  9223372036854775807 = NULL

$ diff <(zdump -v Africa/Cairo | cut -d' ' -f2- ) <(zdump -v Egypt | cut -d' ' -f2- )
```

I noticed that the last DST change in Egypt (or Africa/Cairo) time zone occurred in the year 2014 and there are no provisioned DST changes for Egypt in the current version of time zone information database on my system.

<sup>The last command shows that `Africa/Cairo` and `Egypt` are actually the *same* time zone.</sup>

As an alternative; I had written  [a Perl script](https://kadifeli.com/fedon/hint.php?perl_dst) that will check the DST dates throughout the past and future years. You can test your current or selected time zone using that script also on your system, just to be sure:

```
$ TZ=Egypt ./dstcheck.pl
 Testing seconds from 733276801 to 2200000000...
1993/03/28 Sun 02:00:01 [1993/03/28 Sun 00:00:01 UTC] +2 - Seconds: 733276801
1993/05/01 Sat 02:00:01 [1993/04/30 Fri 23:00:01 UTC] +3 - Seconds: 736210801
1993/10/01 Fri 02:00:01 [1993/10/01 Fri 00:00:01 UTC] +2 - Seconds: 749433601
[...]
2014/06/26 Thu 23:00:01 [2014/06/26 Thu 21:00:01 UTC] +2 - Seconds: 1403816401
2014/08/01 Fri 01:00:01 [2014/07/31 Thu 22:00:01 UTC] +3 - Seconds: 1406844001
2014/09/25 Thu 23:00:01 [2014/09/25 Thu 21:00:01 UTC] +2 - Seconds: 1411678801
```

If you are unfortunate to live in a country where the government makes the "stupidity" (sorry for the term!) to decide for [a DST change in such short notice](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/dst-egypt-2023.html) , you may try to update the time zone files yourself (not an easy task) or wait and hope that they will get updated before April 27.

---

Note: For current time zone information, please go to [IANA Time Zone Database page](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). It seems that the recent Egypt DST change was incorporated into the latest version **2023c** (released on 2023-03-28), so you may hope that Ubuntu will get updated too [very "soon"](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/2023c-0ubuntu0.20.04.0)!

---

### Update (2023-04-13)

As of today, it seems that the updated version (2023c) of [package tzdata](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/tzdata) is available; you can `apt upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade` your system and retry the tests I mentioned above:

```
$ zdump -v Egypt | grep 2023
Egypt  Thu Apr 27 21:59:59 2023 UT = Thu Apr 27 23:59:59 2023 EET isdst=0 gmtoff=7200
Egypt  Thu Apr 27 22:00:00 2023 UT = Fri Apr 28 01:00:00 2023 EEST isdst=1 gmtoff=10800
Egypt  Thu Oct 26 20:59:59 2023 UT = Thu Oct 26 23:59:59 2023 EEST isdst=1 gmtoff=10800
Egypt  Thu Oct 26 21:00:00 2023 UT = Thu Oct 26 23:00:00 2023 EET isdst=0 gmtoff=7200

$ TZ=Egypt dstcheck.pl | grep 2023/
2023/04/28 Fri 01:00:01 [2023/04/27 Thu 22:00:01 UTC] +3 - Seconds: 1682632801
2023/10/26 Thu 23:00:01 [2023/10/26 Thu 21:00:01 UTC] +2 - Seconds: 1698354001
```

If this package seems to be ["kept back"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat) currently, you can wait a few days or just do `apt install tzdata`.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for pointing out the flow from the IANA database to the `tzdata` package to the Ubuntu users. And especially thanks for showing how to check the `tzdata` data.

Answer (score 0):

For all those not able to upgrade tzdata, there's an easy way to update this data by updating the IANA DB

```
wget https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2023c.tar.gz
tar xvzf tzdata2023c.tar.gz
sudo zic africa
sudo zic antarctica
sudo zic asia
sudo zic australasia
sudo zic europe
sudo zic northamerica
sudo zic southamerica
```

Answer (score -3):

First of all let me clarify what you said (If your country has made the "stupidity" (sorry for the term!) to decide for a DST change in such short notice) is not acceptable for any reason or any county, it is rude . I think he asked question and as you wanted to reply you can reply on his question in technical perspective.

And in hus question he just mentioned that clock will be changed on 27th of april but this decision announced long time ago

Comment: The same "stupidity" was made by my government too (several times in the past). Btw, you are right: countries are not stupid, governments are. I will correct my answer in this respect. However it is still stupid to make such changes and allow less than a few years of transition period for all devices to get updated. What will happen to smart phones, IOT devices, mainframes etc. that are updated much less frequently? A chaos should be expected in April 27.